# Can not get links to work in Django project

Tags: django

```
Library/urls.py|
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('catalog/',include('catalog.urls')),
   path('',RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/')),
   path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),


|Catalog/URL.PY|
urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.index,name='index'),
   path('',views.memb,name='memb'),
   path('create_book/',views.BookCreate.as_view(),name='create_book'),
   path('book/<int:pk>/',views.BookDetail.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
   path('my_view/',views.my_view, name='my_view'),

|Catalog/View|
   def memb(request):
      return render(request, 'memb.html',context=context)

|Catalog/index.html|
   <a href="memb.html">MEMBERS</a>

|Catalog/memb.html|
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li> Next menu option.


|ERROR|
```

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/memb.html
Using the URLconf defined in library.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
catalog/ [name='index']
catalog/ [name='memb']
catalog/ create_book/ [name='create_book']
catalog/ book/int:pk/ [name='book_detail']
catalog/ my_view/ [name='my_view']
accounts/
The current path, catalog/memb.html, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page

Says Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/memb.html NOT FOUND!

Why does it not match path: catalog/ [name='memb'] in URLS?

I have tried with and without .html different name selections,whatever.

Please help....Stuck!!!!!

Could it be some conflict with Admin?

Have tried straight html links...same effect???

Comment: Now the homepage called "Index" can not be found?  what is wrong with this software? Do serious developers use this stuff????

Comment: Index file is "missing" Is this serious software?

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is between these two patterns (for this URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/):

```py
path('',views.index,name='index'),
path('',views.memb,name='memb'),
```

Try this:

```
|Catalog/URL.PY|
urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.index, name='index'),
   path('memb/',views.memb, name='memb'), 
   path('create_book/',views.BookCreate.as_view(),name='create_book'),
   path('book/<int:pk>/',views.BookDetail.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
   path('my_view/',views.my_view, name='my_view'),
```

Now change your template:

```
|Catalog/index.html|
   <a href="{% url 'memb' %}">MEMBERS</a>
```

With django you don't need to insert the html file name in the URL, but simply the path you registered in your `urls.py`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243735/discussion-on-answer-by-redwheelbarrow-can-not-get-links-to-work-in-django-proje).

Comment: What views, urls, and reference in <a href do I need just to make a link in Django?